# Serverless SQS consumer skips messages

Tags: amazon-sqs, serverless

I am using the Serverless Framework to consume messages from SQS. Some of the messages sent to the queue do not get consumed. They go straight to the in-flight SQS status and from there to my dead letter queue. When I look at my log of the consumer, I can see that it consumed and successfully processed 9/10 messages. One is always not consumed and ends up in the dead letter queue. I am setting `reservedConcurrency` to 1 so that only one consumer can run at a time. The function consumer `timeout` is set to 30 seconds. This is the consumer code:

```
module.exports.mySQSConsumer = async (event, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  console.log(event.Records);

  await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res();
    }, 100);
  });

  console.log('DONE');

  return true;
}
```

Consumer function configuration follow:

```
functions:
  mySQSConsumer:
    handler: handler.mySQSConsumer
    timeout: 30 # seconds
    reservedConcurrency: 1
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:xyz:my-test-queue
          batchSize: 1
          enabled: true
```

If I remove the `await` function, it will process all messages. If I increase the timeout to 200ms, even more messages will go to straight to the in-flight status and from there to the dead letter queue. This code is very simple. Any ideas why it's skipping some messages? The messages that don't get consumed don't even show up in the log using the first `console.log()` statement. They seem entirely ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The SQS queue Lambda function event triggering works differently than I thought. The messages get pushed into the Lambda function, not pulled by it. I think this could be engineered better by AWS, but it's what it is.

The issue was the `Default Visibility Timeout` set to 30 seconds together with `Reserved Concurrency` set to 1. When the SQS queue gets filled up quickly with thousands of records, AWS starts pushing the messages to the Lambda function at a rate that is faster than the rate at which the single function instance can process them. AWS "assumes" that it can simply spin up more instances of the Lambda to keep up with the backpressure. However, the concurrency limit doesn't let it spin up more instances - the Lambda function is throttled. As a result, the function starts returning failure to the AWS backend for some messages, which will, consequently, hide the failed messages for 30 seconds (the default setting) and put them back into the queue after this period for reprocessing. Since there are so many records to process by the single instance, 30 seconds later, the Lambda function is still busy and can't process those messages again. So the situation repeats itself and the messages go back to invisibility for 30 seconds. This repeats total 3 times. After the third attempt, the messages go to the dead letter queue (we configured our SQS queue that way).

To resolve this issue, we increased the `Default Visibility Timeout` to 5 minutes. That's enough time for the Lambda function to process through most of the messages in the queue while the failed ones wait in invisibility. After 5 minutes, they get pushed back into the queue and since the Lambda function is no longer busy, it will process most of them. Some of them have to go to invisibility twice before being successfully processed.

So the remedy to this problem is either increasing the `Default Invisibility Timeout` like we did or increasing the number of failures necessary before a message goes to the dead letter queue.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Oh my god you are a life saver! The SQS docs do an absolutely terrible job of explaining this. I was in this exact scenario and I couldn't figure out why my lambdas were consuming all the messages in the queue beyond the configured batchSize, and then failing them to the dead letter queue. Thank you so much. You should mark your own answer the right one.

Comment: As an aside, your answer led me to this blog post, which may help someone else understand this better too. https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0

Comment: Glad you wrote that post. I was going to do that myself, but you beat me to it.